# Error map loading for developement purposes only

Tags: google-maps-api-3, visual-studio-code

The map is not loaded well "for development purposes only". I changed the key, but still the map isn't loaded well and after it shows, it disappears.

[image]

```
function initMap() {

    var BORJCEDRIA = { lat: 36.708128, lng: 10.427168 };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 10, center: BORJCEDRIA });
}


<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: One of the subjects of meta question *[Users doing Google first-level customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/users-doing-google-first-level-customer-support)*. (Hence, [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect.))

Comment: I've flagged the question for moderator intervention so that your API key can also be removed from the edit history.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: @BSMP while it is appreciated that you brought this to our attention, we tend to redact PII only, not API keys or tokens. You can use my previous comment to educate the user to reset the keys/tokens instead.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue may be caused by several things such as no billing account link to the project, APIs not enabled in your project or restrictions issue with your API key.

I checked your code and I can see that you provided an API key, I used it with our [simple map sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple#all) and it is throwing a `Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError` which means that the Maps JavaScript API is not activated on your API project.

Follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk) on how to enable multiple APIs in your project.

If you still get the error, please check if your project is linked to a valid billing account and if there are restriction in your API keys that cause this issue. You can also see the different Maps JavaScript Error code on this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#maps-javascript-api-error-codes-for-developers-and-site-owners) for reference in your troubleshooting.

Lastly, I've removed your API key from your answer. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you [restrict](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey) them.